# Should a byte[] be converted to binary for network compression?

Tags: c#, arrays, networking, binary

The data I receive is a byte[] from the application layer. Then in my networking I can send it in **binary** or **raw** format. Is it smaller to convert to binary? Is it a performance hit too much to notice? Should I convert to a string first? Keep in mind I have to receive this data on the other side and a binary compression would automatically deserialize through this networking. In the end I must also convert it back to byte[] to pass it to the application layer. Bandwidth will probably be the bottleneck so this is important.

Comment: To know what is appropriate you'll have to read the documentation of your networking layer, whatever that is. More information please?

Comment: actually using  [peer.js](http://peerjs.com/docs/#peer) which has  [BinaryPack](https://github.com/binaryjs/js-binarypack) compression

Comment: `byte[]` *is* binary data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

byte[] should not be compressed to binary because it is binary data